# group list object with out using groupBy plugin , how to implement

Tags: flutter, dart

***problems***

> group list object with out using **groupBy** plugin , how to implement

this is the input

```
  List<dynamic> data = [
    {"title": "msg1", "message": "hi all", "date": "1969-07-20 20:18:04Z"},
    {"title": "msg2", "message": "hi all", "date": "1969-07-20 20:18:04Z"},
    {"title": "msg2", "message": "hi all", "date": "1969-07-21 20:18:04Z"},
    {"title": "msg2", "message": "hi all", "date": "1969-07-21 20:18:04Z"},
    {"title": "msg2", "message": "hi all", "date": "1969-07-22 20:18:04Z"},
    {"title": "msg2", "message": "hi all", "date": "1969-07-22 20:18:04Z"}
  ];
```

want this output below

```
[
  {
    "date": "1969-07-20 20:18:04Z",
    "message": [
      {
        "title": "msg1",
        "message": "hi all",
        "date": "1969-07-20 20:18:04Z"
      },
      {
        "title": "msg2",
        "message": "hi all",
        "date": "1969-07-20 20:18:04Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": "1969-07-21 20:18:04Z",
    "message": [
      {
        "title": "msg2",
        "message": "hi all",
        "date": "1969-07-21 20:18:04Z"
      },
      {
        "title": "msg2",
        "message": "hi all",
        "date": "1969-07-21 20:18:04Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": "1969-07-22 20:18:04Z",
    "message": [
      {
        "title": "msg2",
        "message": "hi all",
        "date": "1969-07-22 20:18:04Z"
      },
      {
        "title": "msg2",
        "message": "hi all",
        "date": "1969-07-22 20:18:04Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

using the **groupBy** method in **collection** plugin it tack some time , what is the native  dart method to convert the List  to other list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check this Answer , try run in dart pad

```
void main() {
  List<dynamic> data = [
    {"title": "msg1", "message": "hi all", "date": "1969-07-20 20:18:04Z"},
    {"title": "msg2", "message": "hi all", "date": "1969-07-20 20:18:04Z"},
    {"title": "msg2", "message": "hi all", "date": "1969-07-21 20:18:04Z"},
    {"title": "msg2", "message": "hi all", "date": "1969-07-21 20:18:04Z"},
    {"title": "msg2", "message": "hi all", "date": "1969-07-22 20:18:04Z"},
    {"title": "msg2", "message": "hi all", "date": "1969-07-22 20:18:04Z"}
  ];
  
List<dynamic> convertedData = [];
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (i == 0) {
    convertedData.add({
      "date": data[i]["date"],
      "message": [data[i]]
    });
  } else {
    bool found = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < convertedData.length; j++) {
      if (convertedData[j]["date"] == data[i]["date"]) {
        convertedData[j]["message"].add(data[i]);
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!found) {
      convertedData.add({
        "date": data[i]["date"],
        "message": [data[i]]
      });
    }
  }
}
  print(convertedData);
}
```

or using **collection** plugin

```
import "package:collection/collection.dart";

main(List<String> args) {
   List<dynamic> data = [
    {"title": "msg1", "message": "hi all", "date": "1969-07-20 20:18:04Z"},
    {"title": "msg2", "message": "hi all", "date": "1969-07-20 20:18:04Z"},
    {"title": "msg2", "message": "hi all", "date": "1969-07-21 20:18:04Z"},
    {"title": "msg2", "message": "hi all", "date": "1969-07-21 20:18:04Z"},
    {"title": "msg2", "message": "hi all", "date": "1969-07-22 20:18:04Z"},
    {"title": "msg2", "message": "hi all", "date": "1969-07-22 20:18:04Z"}
  ];

var output = groupBy(data,(element) => element["date"])
  .map((key, value) => MapEntry(
        key,
        {"date": key, "message": value.toList()},
      ));

  print(output.values.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    final struct = <String, dynamic>{
      { "product": [ { "name": "cake", "message": "Message1", "time":"2020-06-16" }, { "name": "apple", "message": "Message2", "time": "2020-06-16" }, { "name": "fish", "message": "Message4", "time": "2020-06-15" }, { "name": "toy", "message": "Message5", "time": "2020-06-15" }
] }
    };
```

and add what you need

```
struct["time"] = "2020-06-16";
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below.

```
List dataList=[];

var data={ "product": [ { "name": "cake", "message": "Message1", "time":"2020-06-16" }, { "name": "apple", "message": "Message2", "time": "2020-06-16" }, { "name": "fish", "message": "Message4", "time": "2020-06-15" }, { "name": "toy", "message": "Message5", "time": "2020-06-15" }
] };
```

In init call,

```
dataList.add(data);
```

Print result:

```
[ { "time": "2020-06-16", "product": [ { "name": "cake", "message": "Message1" }, { "name": "apple", "message": "Message2" } ] }, { "time": "2020-06-15", "product": [ { "name": "fish", "message": "Message4' }, { "name": "toy", "message": "Message5" } ]
} ]
```